# Is there a patch to lua for composite operators (+=,-=,*=...)?

Tags: lua, patch, composite, operator-keyword

I know the composite operator is't necessary, but I really want it.

Comment: Note that by patching Lua you lose compatibility with LuaJIT 2 and, well, the rest of the Lua world. Make sure that you have a really good reason before doing that in a commercial project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first stop should be the [power patches pages of the wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaPowerPatches), if that yields nothing, you can try searching through the [mailing list archives](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/), or asking on the mailing list its self.

I'm guessing you'll need to make this one yourself however, using the provided lua source, but the bitwise ops patch on the power patches pages shows you all the places you'd need to patch

Answer (score 0):

Use metalua.
It has a few of these operators built in, and its easy to add more.

Do note the loss of compatibility though.